# Possible to run the same job with different trigger in quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using the following code to create multiple  triggers, and then binding all these triggers to one job. But it failed

```
 "org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'Group.Job', because one already exists with this identification.
"


 for (SchedulerBean schedulerBean : schedulerList) {
            Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("trigger_" + schedulerBean.getConnectorID())
                    .usingJobData("ID", schedulerBean.getConnectorID())
                    .withSchedule(cronSchedule(schedulerBean.crontab))
                    .forJob(job)
                    .build();
            sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
  sched.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error I suspect the  `sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);` part tries to schedule the same job multiple times.

Try adding `sched.addJob(job, true);` before the for loop to add it only once (the 'true' is for replacing old job if exists), and inside the loop use
`sched.scheduleJob(trigger);` instead of `sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);`

The `sched.scheduleJob(trigger);` is able to add the trigger to the job since you specified it with the `.forJob(job)` property